# Is there a software that allows moving of gmail from one account to another?

Tags: email

I'm planning to create another gmail account for business purposes and would like to import all of emails (together with the structure/labels etc., i.e. exactly a mirror copy of the current email setup) from the existing gmail address to a new gmail address. What is the most convenient YET the most reliable way to make this happen. I can give up convenience for reliability. Is there a non-invasive/trustworthy software to make it happen?

Comment: I remember there was a program for backing up Gmail. After backing up you can upload the emails using Thunderbird with a clean addon. That's just an opinion. Notice that while using such programs you should never connect via POP. Otherwise remote content will be deleted.